# In Ruby, how do I split on two or more spaces or a tab?

Tags: ruby, string, split, tabs

With Ruby, how do I split into two or more spaces or a tab?  that is I have:

```
2.4.0 :005 >   str = "a\t\tb   c d"
 => "a\t\tb   c d"
```

and applying my rules above, I would like the result to be:

```
["a", "", "b", "c d"]
```

since the consecutive tabs are capturing an empty string.  But when I try the below:

```
2.4.0 :007 > str.split(/(?:[[:space:]][[:space:]]+|\t)/)
 => ["a", "b", "c d"]
```

The tabs are getting merged into a single `[[:space:]]`.

How do I adjust my regular expression to split into two or more spaces or a tab character?

Comment: `"a\t\tb   c d".split(/  +|\t/)`

Comment: `\s` or `[[:space:]]` covers tabs. So you have to move `\t` in the start - `str.split(/\t|\s{2,}/)`

Comment: THat doesn't work.  If my string is str = "ab \t\t\tf", the above results in  ["ab", "f"], but since i want to split on tabs and there are three tabs in that string, the result shoulld be ["ab ", "", "", "f"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
"a\t\tb   c d".split(/\t| {2,}/)
#=> ["a", "", "b", "c d"]

"ab \t\t\tf".split(/\t| {2,}/)
#=> ["ab ", "", "", "f"]
```

Where `\t` is for *a tab* and `{2,}` for *two or more spaces*. Notice that there is a **space** before `{2,}`.

To include *non-breaking spaces* you could add `\u00A0` to the expression, like this:

```
str.split(/\t|[ |\u00A0]{2,}/)
```

Examples:

```
str = "a\t\tb \u00A0 c d"         #=> "a\t\tb   c d"
str.split(/\t|[ |\u00A0]{2,}/)    #=> ["a", "", "b", "c d"]

str = "ab \t\t\tf"                #=> "ab \t\t\tf"
str.split(/\t|[ |\u00A0]{2,}/)    #=> ["ab ", "", "", "f"]
```

Where `[ |\u00A0]{2,}` will check for 2 or more occurrences of either a *space* or *non-breaking space*.

Comment: Does the clause " {2,}" take into account non-breaking spaces?

Comment: @Dave Can you provide an example string?

Comment: No, I can't.  I ahve read that "[[:space:]]" encompasses both breaking and non-breaking spaces, but when I try your expression using that qualifier, "ab \t\t\tf".split(/\t|[[:space:]]{2,}/), the result is ["ab", "f"], which is not quite what I want.  Maybe I'm wrong about that "[[:space:]]" expression encompassing both things.

Comment: @Dave I tested it and it won't, so you will need to add `\u00A0` to the expression. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work on this one.  I have one more question.  I'm paranoid that there is other types of whitespace that I'm not considering that [[:space:]] covers, for example, "\n".  Is your solution continegent on knowing all possible types of white space and enumerating them in that "[ |\u00A0]" clause?

Comment: @Dave You will need to add all possible types of whitespace, except `\t`, that `[[:space:]]` covers (i.e. `\r`,`\n`,`\v`,`\f`); something like this: `[ |\u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]`.